# How do I import data from SQL Server Views?

Tags: ssas-tabular

How do I Import data into SSAS from SQL server Views? It only shows me Tables. I have views already customized to provide the data the way it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the "Advanced Options" and use SQL.

[image: SQL Server database window]

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW_NAME
```

Note that any filters that reduce the size of the data should be done in your SQL, as Power Query does not do any query folding after an SQL statement. That means if your SQL is like the one above, you will have to wait until every row is sent to Power BI, and then any other filters in your Power Query would be done by Power BI.

If you are not familiar with SQL, set filters with a [WHERE clause](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_where.asp):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'US'
AND COLUMN_2 > 0
```

Comment: You can enable folding over native queries if you use the Value.NativeQuery function (which is not what that designer generates).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding